# knockoutJs and complex processing using stored procedures

Tags: c#, ajax, stored-procedures, knockout.js

We're building an ASP.NET MVC5 website which has let us say some kind of shoppingCart View functionality. KnockoutJs in this scenario, enables to perform calculations such as (UnitPrice * Quantity) for each OrderLineItem and even perform the Total of the shopping Cart Sum(Total of Each line).

Knockout has the client-side Viewmodel containing the data of the Shoppingcart and it can perform Adding, removing, updating of the elements in the ShoppingCart.

Here, in our real-world application, we have let us say the same ShoppingCart, but for doing the processing client-side, it's not as simple as (UnitPrice * Quantity) ... We have complex stored procedures in our Sqlserver database for that purpose.

So, my question : Is this possible to call those storedProcedures via WCF endPoints ? (or Web API ?) like /api/GetResultOfCalculation/ which get the results of the Stored procedure, doing
:

```
   $.ajax({ 
   url : "**/api/GetResultOfCalculation/**",

   data : ko.ToJSON(self),
   content-type : ...
   success : function(data) { 
       // get the results from complex calculations
       // encapsulated in stored procedures
       // and then bind these results to shoppingCart 
       // thus giving the end-user an ajax-like responsiveness
   }
   });
```

Or, is there a possibilty to call the stored procedure via ajax:

I mean, is it possible to make an Ajax call to a controller action which calls the stored procedure `dbo.GetCalculationByXandY` whose results will then get stored in a server-side Viewmodel (S-s Vm).

Then,  this S-s Vm will get serialized into a Client-side ViewModel (C-s Vm) ... that refreshes the ShoppingCart.

What I'm trying to do is AJAX-like responsiveness in my MVC view using KnockoutJs, avoiding roundtrips to the server for each update of Quantity or deletion of OrderItem in shoppingCart. But, as my application has to use stored procedures to perform these calculations, I wonder how this can be done. Any help or suggestion is welcome. Note that it's not possible to do our calculations in c# or javascript, only through stored procedures.

Comment: The question on the surface ("Is this possible?") is *very* narrow, can be answered by a simple "yes". The question you actually want to ask, and somewhat do ask in your last paragraph, is "How to architect this?", is unfortunately too broad for Stack Overflow. What you need is a peer, friend, mentor, colleague, or expert to sit down with you and help you try/build/prototype it.

Comment: How will you create WCF endpoints or service API calls if you can't run code on the server?

Comment: ps - we use aja.js very successfully for api calls in a large knockout ux website http://krampstudio.com/aja.js/.  The backend is Laravel, not ASP.NET, but by using observables and computed observables you can drive the cart via stored procedures so long as you are able to keep the number of api/endpoint calls down per shopping cart transaction.  Otherwise the performance will likely be abysmal

Comment: @Jeroen : yes, how to architect this is my question. Suppose you have a simple shopping cart which need to do complex processing via stored procedures ... what's the best method ?                                                   BrianLMeritt : hi Brian, have you used "aja.js" to get results from stored procedure ? If so, was it responsive ? I think making a round-trip to database server is like a round-trip to a normal server. Ajax is great only while doing client-side processing. (may be I'm answering my own question ?)

Comment: Is KnockOutMvc library good for acheiving this ?